# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n\ln a_n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

> Suppose $a_1=2,a_2=3$ and $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{\ln a_n}$ for every $n\ge 1$. Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{a_n \ln a_n}{n}.$

First, we can prove $a_n>1$, which is easy by induction. Therefore, $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{\ln a_n}>a_{n +1}$, which implies $\{a_n\}$ is increasing. Hence, $\{a_n\}$ either converges to a finite limit, or diverges to the positive infinity. But the former one is impossible. Ortherwise, we assume $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n=a<+\infty$, then $a=a+\dfrac{1}{\ln a}$ by taking the limits of the recursive equility. That equation has no real solution. Therefore, we can claim $a_n \to +\infty(n \to \infty).$

How to go on with this?

Comment: Hint: show that $a_{n+2}\ln{a_{n+2}}-a_{n+1}\ln{a_{n+1}}=1+o(1)$, by showing that $\ln{a_{n+1}}\sim \ln{a_n}$.

Comment: @Mindlack How to prove?

Comment: Just expand $a_{n+2}\ln{a_{n+2}}$ in terms of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, recalling that $\ln(1+x)=x+o(x)$ as $x$ goes to zero.

Comment: In addition to @Mindlack's tip, probably the Stolz–Cesàro theorem can be useful.

Comment: Who can give a full solution？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hints from @Mindlack and @PhoemueX are very useful, and I'll try to give you a full solution here:

Note that $a_n\to +\infty\ (n\to\infty)$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \ln a_{n+2} &= \ln\left(a_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{\ln a_n}\right) \\
 &= \ln a_{n+1}+\ln\big(1+\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}\ln a_n}\big) \\
 &= \ln a_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}\ln a_n}+o\Big(\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}\ln a_n}\Big)
\end{aligned}
$$
so $\dfrac{\ln a_{n+2}}{\ln a_{n+1}} = 1+o(1)$, and then $\dfrac{\ln a_{n+2}}{\ln a_n} = 1+o(1)$ follows. Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 a_{n+2}\ln a_{n+2} &= a_{n+1}\ln a_{n+2} + \dfrac{\ln a_{n+2}}{\ln a_n} \\
 &= a_{n+1}\ln a_{n+1} + \dfrac{1}{\ln a_n} + o\Big(\dfrac{1}{\ln a_n}\Big) + 1 + o(1) \\
 &= a_{n+1}\ln a_{n+1} + 1 + o(1),
\end{aligned}
$$
according to Stolz Theorem, it follows that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a_n\ln a_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \big( a_{n+2}\ln a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}\ln a_{n+1} \big) = 1. $$